# How to remove \ (backslash) from a string?

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I have written a Perl script which reads a list of email addresses from a database and and uses them in a `cc` field to send an email.

```
my $ccList = (($acctType eq 1) ? $sfAdminEmail : $salesCcList);
$ccList =~ s/\\//;

$smtp->cc($ccList);
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("From: $supportEmail\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("To: $toAddress\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("Cc: $ccList\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("Subject: " .$subject. "\r\n");
$smtp->datasend("\r\n");

#Send the message.
$smtp->datasend("$message");
$smtp->datasend("\r\n");
$smtp->dataend();

...
...
```

> For this run, `$acctType = 0` and `$salesCcList = 'pqr3853@gmail.com'`
>   But the message is not reaching the mailbox. Based on the logs, it seems that a backslash in the email address is causing the issue:

```
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)>>> MAIL FROM:<support@xyz3853.in>#015
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)<<< 250 2.1.0 Ok
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)>>> RCPT TO:<abc3853@gmail.com>#015
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)<<< 250 2.1.5 Ok
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)>>> DATA#015
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)<<< 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)>>> From: support@xyz3853.in#015
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)>>> To: abc3853@gmail.com#015
Jan 13 09:20:10 cm cron: Net::SMTP=GLOB(0x98dc480)>>> Cc: pqr3853\@gmail.com#015
```

Comment: You've already got the substitution, it seems. Probably just need `/g`, but without seeing your input data, it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: @MattJacob, initially {/g} was there with the same outcome.

Comment: Like I said, you need to [edit] your post and create a [mcve] if you expect to receive high-quality answers.

Comment: I see you edited your post to include more of the surrounding code, but what you really need to include is `$ccList`. Just set it to something explicit for the sake of this post, since we don't know what's in `$sfAdminEmail` or `$salesCcList` either.

Comment: @MattJacob I have mentioned the values you asked for, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a few lines in your log file:

```
MAIL FROM:<xyz@icmsg.in>#015
<abc@gmail.com>#015
DATA#015
```

the lines end with `#015`, which looks like `octal 015`, which is a `\r`.  It looks to me like when you output `\r\n`, perl is doing automatic newline conversions, so the `\n` is getting converted to `\r\n`, hence the result is `\r\r\n`, i.e. there's an extra `\r`, which is what is appearing in your log file.  That might be harmless until you get to these lines:

```
From: support@xyz3853.in#015
To: abc3853@gmail.com#015
Cc: pqr3853\@gmail.com#015
```

Now the extra `\r` character looks like it is part of the email address.  Would the server know that it is supposed to stop parsing an email address after `.in`?

The example in the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) uses a `\n` to terminate lines in the header, and `\n\n` at the end of the headers.  And from the Net::Cmd [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Cmd.html):

```
datasend ( DATA )
Send data to the remote server, converting LF to CRLF.
```

That means the proper thing to do is to add the necessary number of `\n` chars to the end of a line. `datasend()` handles converting a `\n` character to `\r\n` in order to conform to the spec.

Ack. I missed this:

```
Cc: pqr3853\@gmail.com#015
           ^
           |
```

Is that what you think the problem is?  What's the error code?

Comment: I think the \ is causing the issue, because if I remove the `$smtp->datasend("Cc: $ccList\r\n");` from the code then it reaches to the inbox of **abc3853@gmail.com**. Even if I hardcode the `ccList` to **pqr3853@gmail.com** then also it works. Only problem is when I read `ccList` from DB then it adds the `\ (backslash)` before `@` and the whole thing breaks.

Comment: There is no error code in log, the cc has simply been ignored. If you look at the logs provided above it passes the `From` & `To` successfully with **250 2.1.5 Ok** But does not say anything about `Cc`

Comment: @paper.plane, Does a global substitution solve the problem?

Comment: No, if you meant `$ccList =~ s/\\//g;`

Comment: @paper.plane, Before you do the substitution, can you post the output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($ccList);`  A variable named List, does not sound like it contains a string.  If it is a string, can you also post the output of `printf("%vx \n", $ccList);`  Also, please fix the problem with the `\r\n`.  Having multiple things that are wrong in your code makes it hard to nail down which one is causing the problem.  Even if the extra `\r` chars everywhere do not cause a problem, it's just sloppy coding.